# PineScript | Labels | Bar Location Issue

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have an issue with my script. It is generating alot of Labels in the same location. I think the issue is the "y" variable, but I dont know how to connect it with my input bar location.

[image]

Script:

```
// Input I used | Time
barTime  = input.time(title="Bar Time", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2022 13:30 +0000"), confirm=true)

// Label
SL_label = label.new(
 x = barTime,
 y = close,
 text= trailType == "Long" ? "Long T" : "Short T",
 color = trailType == "Long" ? color.green : color.red,
 style = trailType == "Long" ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_down,
 textcolor = color.white,
 xloc = xloc.bar_time)
```

Comment: Is the issue having multiple labels on the same bar instead of different bars or overlapping labels?

Comment: I want to have only "one" label, that says "Long T". The issue is the code is generating alot of Labels on the same bar. So in away, The issue is with multiple labels on the same bar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you never delete your label.

Add this to the end of your script and it will plot one label.

```
label.delete(SL_label[1])
```